# Getting Comma Separated Dates from multiple rows in SQL using cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp-3.0

I am fairly new to cakephp and I can not figure out how this should be done .Let’s say I have two table, One is employee table and other is attendance table. I want to get the absent dates of the employees in a column where the dates are comma separated. I am using cakephp 3.x and MySQL.

**Employee Table**

```
| ID | Name | email |
-------------------------
|111 |  A   |a.com|
|115 |  B   |b.com|
|176 |  C   |c.com|
|156 |  D   |d.com|
```

**Attendance table**

```
| ID |Employee ID| Date     | Status|
---------------------------------
|1   |  111      |2019-01-06|Present|
|2   |  156      |2019-01-06|Absent |
|3   |  111      |2019-01-07|Present|
|4   |  156      |2019-01-07|Absent |
|5   |  111      |2019-01-08|Absent |
|6   |  156      |2019-01-08|Present|
|7   |  111      |2019-01-09|Absent |
|8   |  156      |2019-01-09|Absent |
```

I want the result to be something similar like below -

**Desired Result**

```
| Employee ID | Name | email | Absent Date          |
-------------------------------------------------------
|111          |  A   |a.com  |2019-01-08,2019-01-09|
|156          |  D   |d.com  |2019-01-06,2019-01-07,2019-01-09|
```

I have tried this with group_concat(date) but it gives an warning saying "Failed to parse time string" then "Uncaught Error: Call to a member function on Boolean".

**Edit**

I have tried--

```
$query = $this->Attendance->find()
        ->contain(['Employees'])
        ->select(['Employees.id','Employees.name','Employees.email','date'=>'goup_concat(Attendance.date)'])
->distinct('Employees.id)->toArray();
```

It gives a warning --

```
DateTimeImmutable:modify(): Failed to parse time string
and Error:Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format()on boolean
```

Please help to get the desired result.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show what you have already tried, it may be easier to show where you went wrong.

Comment: Do you need them to be comma separated for some reason related to other code, or you just want to show them comma separated in a view somewhere?

Comment: I just want to show them as comma separated in a view. Any help would be appreciated. @GregSchmidt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you don't need the query to make them comma-separated, so that's something better done in the view. Along these lines (untested):

```
$query = $this->Employees->find()
    ->contain(['Attendance' => [
        'queryBuilder' => function (Query $q) {
            return $q->where(['Attendance.status' => 'Absent']);
        }
    ]]);
```

This will get the list of employees with all their absent attendance records. (If you need to get *only* employees that were absent at least once, you can use `->matching(...)` to do this.

Then in your view:

```
foreach ($query as $employee) {
    // Output $employee->id, name, email, you know how to do that
    echo implode(',', collection($employee->attendance)->extract('Date')->toArray());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use plain sql query, you do it like this, join employees table with attendance table and use `group_concat` with `if` function to get absence dates into a list :

```
SELECT emp.ID, 
       emp.Name, 
       emp.email, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(IF(att.Status = 'Absent', att.Date, NULL) SEPARATOR ',') AS `Absent Date`  
FROM   Employee emp
JOIN   Attendance att
ON     emp.ID = att.`Employee ID`
GROUP BY emp.ID, emp.Name, emp.email
```

[Demo<>dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ea27581043a9a26b9da8db39de8acd11)